Opacity/Blending Issue in HTML/CSS
I am making a website to organize some information for myself, for whatever reason, one of my divs seems to overlap with another div, despite having a higher z-index than the div it is overlapping with. My assumption is that this is happening due to some sort of hierarchy/parental issue
Essentially, when I hover over the "Metasploit Suite" or the "Other Exploitation Tools" the "drop-wrapper-cont" div appears as expected, however it seems to do some strange blending/opacity shifting/overlaying with the Upload/Download's .section-wrapper div
Here is my HTML for the relevant section:


body {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 1), rgba(0,0,0,.85));
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
}
body * {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.border-div {
    background: darkgray;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: black 10px solid;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgb(255, 132, 132);
    margin: 30px;
    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
}
.ind {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
.home-button {
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px white solid;
    box-shadow: red 0 0 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.home-button:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.home-button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.home-button:hover a {
    color: black;
}
.click-open {
    display: none;
}
.click-header {
    display: block;
    width: fit-content;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer; 
    user-select: none;
}
.click-header:hover {
    color: red;
}
.code {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .2);
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.section-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    box-shadow: black 0 0 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    animation: slideUp 1s ease-out forwards;
}
.section-wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}
h1 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.hl-both::after {
    content: "[BOTH]";
    background: yellow; 
    color: black; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hl-pass::after {
    content: "[PASS]";
    background: red; 
    color: white; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hl-hash::after {
    content: "[HASH]";
    background: orange; 
    color: black; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.inlay-link::before {
    content: "[+]\00a0";
}
.inlay-link {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.inlay-link:hover {
    color: red;
}
.ul-format {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.mkdwn-img {
    height: 30px; 
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: none;
    transition: transform 2s;
    position: relative;
}
.mkdwn-img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.75);
}
.explain-me {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: fit-content;
}
.font-size-wrapper {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.explain-me-cont {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
    width: 200px;
    height: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.explain-me:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: gray;
}
.explain-me:hover .explain-me-cont {
    display: inline-block;
}
.drop-wrapper {
    display: relative;
}
.drop-wrapper:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.drop-wrapper-cont {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    left: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px white solid;
}
.drop-wrapper:hover .drop-wrapper-cont {
    display: block;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
    from {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css"/>
        <title>C3 Wiki</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="border-div">
            <p>Links will become red on hover</p>
            <p>Menus will appear over certain items (Those without a [+])</p>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1>Hash & Password Cracking</h1>
                <ul class="ul-format" style="color: white;">
                    <li>
                        <div class="drop-wrapper"><span class="hl-both ">John Suite&nbsp;</span>
                            <div class="drop-wrapper-cont">
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/cracking/john.html#john"><span class="hl-pass">john&nbsp;</span></a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/cracking/john.html#unshadow"><span class="hl-pass">unshadow&nbsp;</span></a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/cracking/john.html#zip2john"><span class="hl-hash">zip2john&nbsp;</span></a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/cracking/john.html#rar2john"><span class="hl-hash">rar2john&nbsp;</span></a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/cracking/john.html#ssh2john"><span class="hl-hash">ssh2john&nbsp;</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link hl-pass" href="./pages/cracking/cracking.html#hydra">Hydra&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link hl-hash" href="./pages/cracking/cracking.html#hashcat">Hashcat&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link hl-hash" href="https://hashes.com/en/decrypt/hash" target="_blank">hashes.com&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link hl-hash" href="https://crackstation.net/" target="_blank">Crackstation&nbsp;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1>Discovery/Enumeration</h1>
                <h2>Directory</h2>
                <ul class="ul-format">
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/discovery/directory.html#gobuster">gobuster</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/discovery/directory.html#dirb">dirb</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/discovery/directory.html#dirbuster">dirbuster</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/discovery/directory.html#find">find</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h2>Protocol Enumeration</h2>
                <ul class="ul-format">
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/discovery/protocol-enum.html#enum4linux">Enum4Linux</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/discovery/protocol-enum.html#nmap">NMAP</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/discovery/protocol-enum.html#dnsenum">DNSenum and Dig</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1>Exploitation</h1>
                <ul class="ul-format">
                    <li>
                        <div class="drop-wrapper"><span style="color: white;">Metasploit Suite</span>
                            <div class="drop-wrapper-cont">
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#meterpreter">Meterpreter</a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#msfconsole">Metasploit Framework Console<span style="font-size: 10px; padding-right: 2px; color: green;">(msfconsole)</span></a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#searchsploit">Searchsploit</a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#msfvenom">Msfvenom</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="drop-wrapper"><span style="color: white;">Other Exploitation Tools</span>
                            <div class="drop-wrapper-cont">
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/other_exploitation.html#smbmap">SMBMap</a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/other_exploitation.html#linpeas">LinPEAS/WinPEAS</a>
                                <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/other_exploitation.html#wpscan">WPScan</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1>File Downloads / Uploads</h1>
                <ul class="ul-format">
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./  pages/upload/updown.html#wget">wget</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#smbget">smbget</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#git">git clone</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#python">python web server</a></li>
                    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#curl">curl</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1><a class="click-header" onclick="showItem('xss')">XSS (Cross-Site Scripting)</a></h1>
                <div id="xss" class="click-open">
                    <p>(Hover over each part for an explanation)</p>
                    <p>SQL Injection example:</p>
                    <div class=font-size-wrapper>
                        <div class="explain-me">&lt;string&gt;
                            <div class="explain-me-cont" style="background: green;">Input to initiate, can be any string or normal characters (non-escape)</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="explain-me" >'
                            <div class="explain-me-cont" style="background: red;">The escape character to exit out of text processing</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="explain-me">OR 1=1
                            <div class="explain-me-cont" style="background: blue;">Logical operation so that the program returns true</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="explain-me">--
                            <div class="explain-me-cont" style="background: yellow; color: black;">-- is a comment in SQL, so when the program interprets this it is used maliciously by us to end the program and return</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1><a class="click-header" onclick="showItem('netcat')">Netcat</a></h1>
                <div id="netcat" class="click-open">
            
                    <ul>
                        <li>Create a listener for a reverse shell: <span class="code">nc -lnvp PORT</span> <span style="font-size: 30px;">&larr; Inbound</span></li>
                        <li>Initiate a connection: <span class="code">nc 192.168.0.1 1234</span> <span style="font-size: 30px;">&rarr; Outbound</span></li>
                    </ul>      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1><a class="click-header" onclick="showItem('commands')">Other Helpful Commands</a></h1>
                <div id="commands" class="click-open">
                    <ul>
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><span class="code">ip addr | grep inet</span> - Your machine's IP (UNIX only)</li>
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><span class="code">ip addr | grep tun0</span> - Your tunnel's (VPN) IP (UNIX only)</li>
                        <li><span class="code">ipconfig /all | findstr /i ipv4</span> Your machine's IP (Windows only)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1><a class="click-header" onclick="showItem('dns')">DNS Records</a></h1>
                <div id="dns" class="click-open">
                    <ul>
                        <li>A - Hostname &rarr; IPv4</li>
                        <li>AAAA - Hostname/Domain &rarr; IPv6</li>
                        <li>NS - Domain &rarr; Nameserver</li>
                        <li>MX - Domain &rarr; Mailserver</li>
                        <li>CNAME - Hostname &larr;&rarr; Hostname</li>
                        <li>TXT - Text Record</li>
                        <li>HINFO - Host Information</li>
                        <li>SOA - Start of Authority (Domain Authority)</li>
                        <li>SRV - Service Records</li>
                        <li>PTR - IP &rarr; Hostname</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper">
                <h1><a class="click-header" onclick="showItem('links')">Other Helpful Links</a></h1>
                <div id="links" class="click-open">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bypass security restrictions in misconfigured systems: <a class="inlay-link" style="display: inline !important;" href="https://gtfobins.github.io/">GTFOBins</a></li>
                        <li>Reverse shell cheat sheet: <a class="inlay-link" style="display: inline !important;" href="https://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet">pentestmonkey</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function showItem(id) {
                var x = document.getElementById(id);
                if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") {
                    x.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>



I have attempted to change the z-index value of all of these divs several times, setting the drop-wrapper-cont to something ridiculous like "999" or .section-wrapper to "-1". I have also tried experimenting with the "mix-blend-mode" option, but to no avail. I'm just stumped because I've been sitting here trying things repeatedly, but it seems that I may have to restructure the HTML so that the parents aren't doing funny things with the z-index?
EDIT: Included full HTML/CSS, original snippet of relevant code did not change the visual with provided correct answer

Please provide a minimal – but still working – example, in a runnable code snippet.

@Éric My apologies, I didn't know that this was a requirement. Thank you for adding it.

You have a semi transparent grayish color on the elements so when the drop down happens (and goes behind the second section as it is first in the DOM) you see it vaguely thro' the gray. Try making that gray into a solid color and see the bottom of the dropdown disappear.

@AHaworth I am poking around a bit here. I changed the color of .section-wrapper to a solid contrasting red. I see now that the .drop-wrapper-cont just goes fully underneath it then.

Yes, that's right. You need to lift the z-index of the first section so the drop down goes over the second one.

@AHaworth That fixed it, I just added some inline CSS raising the z-index of the first section-wrapper up by 1. I was slightly confused because entirely removing the animation allows it to render properly as well, is there any reason for this? Thank you!

transform creates a new stacking context (not sure that's a totally satisfactory explanation, but maybe it's a start).

@AHaworth I read up on stacking contexts a few nights ago That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for all the help and explanation.

FWIW this really looks like too much CSS here - probably because of all the position:... stuff and places it is not DRY as it could be.  A good indication of your issue is when you mouse over "Other Exploitation Tools" then the pop-up window if you mouse down the menu the bottom never can be moused over - thus it is "under" something else.

@MarkSchultheiss I agree, it is too much CSS. I'm just making this for some coworkers to organize some notes and provide resources to locations, otherwise I'd organize the CSS a bit better, I just wanted it to look presentable. I'm not a web developer at all, I've taken one course for it. But yes, the issue has been fixed. Thanks for the notes

Remove the z-index from the .section-wrapper element so the second .section-wrapper element does not overlay any child element of the first.


.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  box-shadow: black 0 0 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  animation: slideUp 1s ease-out forwards;
}

.section-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}


}
h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.inlay-link::before {
  content: "[+]\00a0";
}
.inlay-link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.inlay-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
.drop-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.drop-wrapper:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.drop-wrapper-cont {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  left: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px white solid;
}
.drop-wrapper:hover .drop-wrapper-cont {
  display: block;
}
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <h1>Exploitation</h1>
  <ul class="ul-format">
    <li>
      <div class="drop-wrapper"><span style="color: white;">Metasploit Suite</span>
        <div class="drop-wrapper-cont">
          <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#meterpreter">Meterpreter</a>
          <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#msfconsole">Metasploit Framework Console<span style="font-size: 10px; padding-right: 2px; color: green;">(msfconsole)</span></a>
          <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#searchsploit">Searchsploit</a>
          <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/metasploit.html#msfvenom">Msfvenom</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="drop-wrapper"><span style="color: white;">Other Exploitation Tools</span>
        <div class="drop-wrapper-cont">
          <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/other_exploitation.html#smbmap">SMBMap</a>
          <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/other_exploitation.html#linpeas">LinPEAS/WinPEAS</a>
          <a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/exploitation/other_exploitation.html#wpscan">WPScan</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="section-wrapper">
  <h1>File Downloads / Uploads</h1>
  <ul class="ul-format">
    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./  pages/upload/updown.html#wget">wget</a></li>
    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#smbget">smbget</a></li>
    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#git">git clone</a></li>
    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#python">python web server</a></li>
    <li><a class="inlay-link" href="./pages/upload/updown.html#curl">curl</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




I applied the edit, and I see that in your code snippet it was working, but nothing changed on the full website, leading me to believe that there is another issue elsewhere. I edited the relevant HTML & CSS in the main post and applied your change.
